# Haskell. Recursive Lambda. Errors

Tags: haskell

```
y :: (f->f) -> f
y f = f (y f)

indexOf :: Char -> String -> Maybe Int
indexOf c l = 
    y(\ ff c (h:t) pos -> 
        if ( c == h) then Just pos
            else ff c t (pos + 1)
        )(c, l, 0)

indexOf c [] = Nothing
```

It gives me two compilation errors:
The code should find position of char c in string. For example:
indexOf('a', 'lamp') = 2

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[(Char, String, Integer)]
                                  -> Integer -> Maybe Integer'
                with actual type `Maybe Int'
    The lambda expression `\ ff c (h : t) pos -> ...'
    has four arguments,
    but its type `((Char, String, Integer) -> Maybe Int)
                  -> (Char, String, Integer) -> Maybe Int'
    has only two
    In the first argument of `y', namely
      `(\ ff c (h : t) pos
          -> if (c == h) then Just pos else ff c t (pos + 1))'
    In the expression:
      y (\ ff c (h : t) pos
           -> if (c == h) then Just pos else ff c t (pos + 1))
        (c, l, 0)


    Couldn't match expected type `[(Char, String, Integer)]
                                  -> Integer -> Maybe Integer'
                with actual type `Maybe Int'
    The function `ff' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `(Char, String, Integer) -> Maybe Int' has only one
    In the expression: ff c t (pos + 1)
    In the expression: if (c == h) then Just pos else ff c t (pos + 1)
```

I don't know how to repair it. Please give me a hand :)

Comment: Haskell functions are called `function a b c ...` not `function(a,b,c,...)`. The structure `(a,b,c,...)` is called a tuple, but the function defined doesn't take one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem here is that you mix *tuples* and curried arguments (you should try to stay with the basic form of two curried arguments if you don't want to change `y`) - but your thinking is quite good!

indeed it's only a few small changes to get it working:

```
indexOf :: Char -> String -> Maybe Int
indexOf c ls = 
    y(\ ff (ls, pos) ->
       case ls of
         (h:t)
           | h == c -> Just pos
           | otherwise -> ff (t, pos+1)
         [] -> Nothing
     )(ls, 0)
```

as you can see I did:

- moved the case-split inside
- rewrote the arguments into a tuple of the *rest*-list and the position
- reused the `c` from the closure you get for free ;)

here is it in action:

```
λ> indexOf 'l' "Hello"
Just 2
λ> indexOf 'a' "Hello"
Nothing
```

---

of course while this is a good exercise you should not really write Haskell this way - the obvious direct recursion is a lot more readable:

```
indexOf :: Char -> String -> Maybe Int
indexOf c = indexOf' 0
  where 
    indexOf' _ [] = Nothing
    indexOf' pos (h:t)
      | c == h = Just pos
      | otherwise = indexOf' (pos+1) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You said that I am mixing a currying and tuples. I cannot see it.
If I understand correctly: In your example you used a currying. Am I right?

Comment: `y(\ ff c (h:t) pos -> ...)(c, l, 0)` calls `y` with one argument, not three as you intend. `(c, l, 0)` is a three-tuple, remember.

Comment: @Gilgamesz Carsten showed how to use tuples both in the lambda patterns and the arguments: `y(\ff (ls, pos) -> ...)(ls, 0)`. You can also use a curried version simply removing tuples in both places: `y(\ff ls pos -> ...) ls 0`. Both are fine, but mixing the two approaches will cause a type mismatch.

Comment: @Carsten, I appreciated your piece of code. A lot of knowledge for me, as beginner!